# String to language constant?

Tags: php

How can i create a language constant instead of a classic text?

I tried it so:

```
$langConstant = strtoupper(str_replace (' ', '', $this->fieldsClass->getFieldName($oneExtraField)));
$langConstant = str_replace('-', '', $langConstant);
```

I try to reproduce my content from override file so, but i see only constant code:

```
echo JText::_("TPL_CTM_F_$langConstant");
or
echo JText::_("TPL_CTM_F_" . $langConstant);
```

How can i reproduce it as language constant?

Answer (score 6):

The Language constant that youre trying to build will work if the final, full constant is defined in your language file.  In other words, if you set `$langConstant = 'XYZ'`, then `TPL_CTM_F_XYZ` must exist in the language file that you are using.

All of these will work, (knowing that `JYES` and `JNO` are found in a language file)

```
echo JText::_("JYES");
echo JText::_("JNO");

$variable = 'JYES';
echo JText::_($variable);

$yes = strtoupper('yes');
$constructed = 'J'.$yes;
echo JText::_($constructed);

echo JText::_('J'.strtoupper('yes'));
```

You define Language strings in the language folder of your component.  These are typically located in `\language\en-GB` from the root of your site, or within the components folder (where 'en-GB' is your language).  That language file is loaded with your component and the rest is taken care of by Joomla.

See [Creating a Language File](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_language_definition_file) and [Specification of Language Files](https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files). If you need a language string from other than your component, see how to do at [Loading Extra Language Files](https://docs.joomla.org/Loading_extra_language_files).

Additionally, in the Administrator, you can add and maintain language strings using the Language Manager.